# Running a binary directly works fine, but fails with execve

Tags: nix, execve

I have a very curious case that I spent a week trying to debug to no avail. For context, I want to start playing with the nix package manager and I made myself a tiny chroot environment from one of the Alpine base images. I have successfully installed the nix package manager as can be seen from:

```
# nix --version
nix (Nix) 2.9.2
```

I have executed the usual

```
# nix-channel --add "https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable"
```

And verified that it works successfully by running:

```
# nix-channel --list
nixpkgs https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable
```

However, when I am trying to run `nix-channel --update`, I am getting:

```
# nix-channel --update
unpacking channels...
error: executing '/usr/bin/nix-env': No such file or directory
error: program '/usr/bin/nix-env' failed with exit code 1
```

Okay, it says `nix-env` is not available, but:

```
# /usr/bin/nix-env --version
nix-env (Nix) 2.9.2
# type -p nix-env
/usr/bin/nix-env
# nix-env --version
nix-env (Nix) 2.9.2
```

It actually exists, so I started to dig deeper, and go my strace (relevant excerpt):

```
[pid 30861] vfork(strace: Process 30880 attached
 <unfinished ...>
[pid 30880] prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGKILL) = 0
[pid 30880] dup2(12, 1)                 = 1
[pid 30880] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid 30880] getcwd("/", 4096)           = 2
[pid 30880] setns(3, CLONE_NEWNS)       = 0
[pid 30880] chdir("/")                  = 0
[pid 30880] prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=65536*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
[pid 30880] prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = 0
[pid 30880] mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efc7fa67000
[pid 30880] execve("/usr/bin/nix-env", ["/usr/bin/nix-env", "--profile", "/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/r"..., "--file", "/tmp/nix.pmkgai", "--install", "--remove-all", "--from-expression", "f: f { name = \"nixpkgs\"; channel"..., "--quiet"], 0x7ffc38f7aac0 /* 11 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Rather very strange. I got nix sources out of curiosity and added some debugging info around the `execve` invocation. Grabbing the command line that is executed works fine on the console when run manually. Replaced the call to `/usr/bin/nix-env` with (slightly modified version of) `/bin/echo`, which executed successfully and produced the result I expected (nix guys should really look at providing better runtime debugging information, because at the moment [`nix-env` is `execve`d with `--quiet` flag](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/609779086301a600f4282a629d586bba6b6a485c/src/nix-channel/nix-channel.cc#L142) and the output is [not even propagated back to the user](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/609779086301a600f4282a629d586bba6b6a485c/src/libutil/util.cc#L1044-L1045), so it is not possible to know what happened, but that’s a GitHub issue for another day `/rant off`).

Anyway, I digress a bit. The question I have, what could be causing this? Why does `nix-env` work just fine from the command line, but fails under `execve`?

I did my usual checks on what interpreter is expected:

```
# readelf -l /usr/bin/nix-env | grep interpreter
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1]
# ls -la /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        604704 Apr  8 05:38 /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
```

As well as making sure all dynamic libraries are properly resolved:

```
# ldd /usr/bin/nix-env 
    /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7fc0b3d20000)
    libnixexpr.so => /usr/lib/libnixexpr.so (0x7fc0b378a000)
    libgc.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgc.so.1 (0x7fc0b3721000)
    libnixmain.so => /usr/lib/libnixmain.so (0x7fc0b36d7000)
    libnixfetchers.so => /usr/lib/libnixfetchers.so (0x7fc0b35dd000)
    libnixstore.so => /usr/lib/libnixstore.so (0x7fc0b3229000)
    libnixutil.so => /usr/lib/libnixutil.so (0x7fc0b30eb000)
    libnixcmd.so => /usr/lib/libnixcmd.so (0x7fc0b3027000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x7fc0b2dd9000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x7fc0b2dba000)
    libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 => /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7fc0b3d20000)
    libboost_context.so.1.80.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_context.so.1.80.0 (0x7fc0b2db5000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x7fc0b2cbd000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4 (0x7fc0b2c3f000)
    libsodium.so.23 => /usr/lib/libsodium.so.23 (0x7fc0b2bed000)
    libseccomp.so.2 => /usr/lib/libseccomp.so.2 (0x7fc0b2bd1000)
    libcrypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.3 (0x7fc0b2817000)
    libbrotlidec.so.1 => /usr/lib/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x7fc0b280b000)
    libbrotlienc.so.1 => /usr/lib/libbrotlienc.so.1 (0x7fc0b2787000)
    libarchive.so.13 => /usr/lib/libarchive.so.13 (0x7fc0b26e0000)
    libcpuid.so.15 => /usr/lib/libcpuid.so.15 (0x7fc0b26c5000)
    libeditline.so.1 => /usr/lib/libeditline.so.1 (0x7fc0b26ba000)
    libnghttp2.so.14 => /usr/lib/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x7fc0b2691000)
    libssl.so.3 => /usr/lib/libssl.so.3 (0x7fc0b25fc000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x7fc0b25e2000)
    libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /usr/lib/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x7fc0b25bf000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib/libacl.so.1 (0x7fc0b25b5000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib/libexpat.so.1 (0x7fc0b2590000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /usr/lib/liblzma.so.5 (0x7fc0b256d000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /usr/lib/libzstd.so.1 (0x7fc0b24f7000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/liblz4.so.1 (0x7fc0b24d8000)
    libbz2.so.1 => /usr/lib/libbz2.so.1 (0x7fc0b24c9000)
```

Any pointers in the right direction are highly appreciated.

**EDIT**: Adding a `strace -v` run to see what environment is passed down to the `nix-env` invocation (as suggested in one of the comments):

```
[pid 18800] execve("/usr/bin/nix-env", ["/usr/bin/nix-env", "--profile", "/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/r"..., "--file", "/tmp/nix.aCocaf", "--install", "--remove-all", "--from-expression", "f: f { name = \"nixpkgs\"; channel"..., "--quiet"], ["CHARSET=UTF-8", "PWD=/root", "HOME=/root", "LANG=C.UTF-8", "TMPDIR=/tmp", "SHLVL=1", "PAGER=less", "PS1=\\h:\\w\\$ ", "LC_COLLATE=C", "PATH=/nix/var/nix/profiles/defau"..., "OLDPWD=/root", "_=/usr/bin/strace"]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Unfortunately, no `LD_*` environment variables are manipulated or passed down to the `nix-env` call.

**EDIT**: Digging further, I built a very minimal statically-linked Rust app that writes the command line and the environment to the log file when it is executed, and replaced the `nix-env` with it. Getting the same problem.

Comment: Interesting. FWIW, in NixOS there is no `/usr/bin/nix-env`; instead, it lives under `/nix/store` and all its library dependencies have explicit rpaths telling the linker the exact store locations in which to find them. If you're interested in doing a serious evaluation of Nix, I strongly advise its native environment.

Comment: Eventually, but that isn't my point. I am now too invested to know what is going on with that `execve` magic.

Comment: BTW, if you look at what your shell does during a direct invocation, you'll see execve there too. If instead of being a trivial Alpine instance this were a heavyweight distro with security tools that allowed filtering of which executables are allowed to exec others, f/e, I might look there (since you've ruled out the dynamic linker, which was my first guess too). Or look at filesystem namespace changes within the process.

Comment: That said, I wonder if you might find something interesting in invoking the executable via the dynamic linker explicitly, or putting a wrapper at the relevant `/usr/bin` location.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you very much for the ideas. I have discovered the source of the problem (see the accepted answer), but I appreciate your attention and input on this matter!

Comment: Thank you for the research you did in digging into this question; I learned something too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say that you use a chroot environment. Your strace log contains `setns(CLONE_NEWNS)`, which means that nix uses mount namespaces. By looking at nix source code, it seems that when nix starts, it saves the current mount namespace and restores it in forked children by the `setns` call. Maybe, this way `nix` can escape from the chroot, to a place, where your binaries are not available. This would explain why neither `nix-env` nor your Rust static binary could have been executed, but `/bin/echo` could (provided that you have `/bin/echo` also outside of your chroot).

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for this hint. I am not very familiar with namespacing in Linux (I know it exists and know how/why to use it, but never dug into how it's actually implemented and all the implications it has, so `setns()` didn't raise an alarm for me), so it is perfect time to learn about it. I just placed a fake script into the `/usr/bin/nix-env` into the host system itself and everything worked. This gives me enough info to work myself out of this problem! Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is caused by the dynamic linker. Maybe `nix` sets or unsets some `LD_*` benvironment variables, which make the linker fail. I'd run `strace` with `-v` and look at `execve` environment, which will be shown instead of `0x7ffc38f7aac0` in your log.

You also didn't say how did you install nix. It looks like you use Alpine package. Maybe, there is a bug in the packaging. You can try installing nix according to [the "official" instructions](https://nixos.org/download.html) and compare the results.

Edit: It's unexpected that `ldd nix-env` shows the libraries from `/usr`. Correct Nix installation should link the libraries from the `/nix/store`. Also, the "official" nix installation uses the Nix's dynamic linker (from `/nix/store`) and not the one from hosting distribution. I guess that the packaging removed *runpath* from the binary. This is how it should look like:

```
readelf --all $(which nix-env)|grep runpath
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/nix/store/1psw6gi16i6188ww3clbnxaqr3mp9hqy-nix-2.9.1/lib:/nix/store/mg7kp9pnfi3ihbf0dch41yv1p7rkmhk2-libsodium-1.0.18/lib:/nix/store/p3zp0lj11q9rv2an3i9qcmz2bj2k2qbg-editline-1.17.1/lib:/nix/store/i5nd8pcr0qfig61ssizdhywx9jhfim5j-boehm-gc-8.0.6/lib:/nix/store/vp2xibvh06s5hv3sygcnjdjnrnhj6gjx-lowdown-1.0.0-lib/lib:/nix/store/d2bpliayddadf6lx6l1i04w265gqw8n6-glibc-2.34-210/lib:/nix/store/q9gfnkp0zaafccpgj4mqngmp9f9y93xh-gcc-11.3.0-lib/lib
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will have a look at environment a bit closer. Nix is installed by compiling it from the source and doing `make install`. Let's put aside correctness of installation or whatever is recommended approach for a moment here. I am truly curious to know why `nix-env` works fine on manual invocation vs being executed from another binary using `execve` more than anything.

Comment: Just did `strace -vf` and attached the `execve()` log entry, nothing suspicious so far.